# How can I populate a set of inputs with the data from the json object

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a json object that is loaded by jquery ajax & populates my select like so:

```
function populateSelect(url, selectId) {

    var sel = $(selectId);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            sel.empty();
            sel.append('<option value="" selected></option>');
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                sel.append('<option value="' + [i] + '">' + data[i].BusinessName + '</option>');
            }
        }
    });

};

populateSelect('/api/buninesses', '#business');
```

example json that it returns:

```
[{"BusinessID":123,"BusinessName":"Test1","ContactName":"John Doe"},
{"BusinessID":456,"BusinessName":"Test2","ContactName":"Sally Smith"}]
```

example select that it creates:

```
<select id="business">
    <option value=""></select>
    <option value="0">Test1</select>
    <option value="1">Test2</select>
</select>
```

---

**When some changes the select how can I populate a set of inputs with the data from the json object?**

For example if someone chooses "Test1" then I want to populate the inputs with the correct data from the json object for the selection:

```
<input id ="BusinessID" value="123">
<input id ="BusinessName" value="Test1">
<input id ="ContactName" value="John Doe">
```

if they choose "Test2" then the inputs should look like this:

```
<input id ="BusinessID" value="456">
<input id ="BusinessName" value="Test2">
<input id ="ContactName" value="Sally Smith">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the object as json to the data attribute of the select option

```
sel.append('<option value="' + [i] + 
  '" data="' + escape(JSON.stringify(data[i])) + '">' + 
  data[i].BusinessName + '</option>');
```

Then, when a value is selected, parse the json from the data attribute of the selected option and assign it to the input fields.

```
$("#business").change(function() {
   var obj = JSON.parse(unescape($("#business option:selected").attr('data')));
   $("#BusinessId").val(obj.BusinessID);
   $("#BusinessName").val(obj.BusinessName);
   $("#ContactName").val(obj.ContactName);
});
```

Check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7e86ns8z/) for a working example.

Comment: I thought it was a good idea storing the json string in the data attribute as u suggested but it breaks the select options because of all the quotation marks in the json string.. Any ideas?

Comment: ended up just using javascript to escape/unescape the data attribute.. thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok, you have found a solution. I was looking for it. I have updated the answer.